# Creating a backend typescript module in react-typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax-error

## What I want to happen

I'm working on a react project which I created using `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript`

I need to access local files so my plan was to create a Rest API. In order to do that I wanted to create some `.ts` files that contain some functions, and later make them accessible through an API.

## What I tried

I created a simple `test.ts` typescript file (I've tried with `.ts` and `.tsx` but that made no difference) that would only `console.log()` something to the console. I ran the code using the [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) package. I've used `ts-node` many times and I know it works fine.

The command I used for running is `node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./src/backend/test.ts`
After I ran the code I got the following error: `All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.` which I solved by adding `export {}` to the start of the file.

Then i had this code that is working:

```js
export {}
const someFunc = () =>{
    console.log('Hello typescript')
}
someFunc()
```

#### The error:

Later, I tried to export the function to another file but I've encountered a weird problem: **I couldn't export anything.**

I tried this code:

```js
export const someFunc = () =>{
    console.log('Hello typescript')
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
...\src\backend\test.ts:1
export var someFunc = function () {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module.m._compile (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:473:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:476:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:158:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

How can I solve this problem? Or how should I create backend using typescript in a typescript react project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `export var someFunc`. looks like es module syntax is not transpiled, can you show related config?

Comment: Do you mean the `tsconfig.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, it seems to be related to your tsconfig. `export var someFunc` some es module syntax is not transpiled.

Make sure in your tsconfig, you have `"module": "commonjs"` instead of `es2015`, `es`, etc

Or you could use a separate config, eg `ts-node -p tsconfig.cjs.json`

Comment: This solved my problem but after I run `npm start` to run the react website, the `tsconfig.json` `"module"` field is changed to `esnext`.

Comment: that might be related to `create-react-app` itself, maybe it is changing the module because bundler can handle it and need it to perform static import analysis (tree-shaking). Thus the transpiled code is not runnable directly as it need to go through another transformation by bundler.

Comment: In short you need a separate tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Typescript backend working with Typescript React client, then you can have a look at the [crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) project.